# How to show nested table inside react-dataTable-component

Tags: reactjs, mern, react-table, react-data-table-component

I want to show a nested table when expand the rows,below i have provided my component.How to achieve this.I am trying but when expand row getting there are no records found text.

I want to show a nested table when expand the rows,below i have provided my component.How to achieve this.I am trying but when expand row getting there are no records found text.

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    Row,
    Card,
    // Table,
    CardBody,
    // Collapse,
    CardTitle,
    InputGroup,
    CustomInput,
    InputGroupAddon,
    Input,
    // DropdownToggle,
    // DropdownItem,
    // DropdownMenu,
    // UncontrolledDropdown,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Form,
    Button,
    // Col,
    // Badge,
} from 'reactstrap';
import { Colxx, Separator } from 'components/common/CustomBootstrap';
import Breadcrumb from 'containers/navs/Breadcrumb';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';

const columns = [
    {
        name: 'S.No.',
        selector: 'sNo',
        sortable: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'Name',
        selector: 'name',
        sortable: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'R.No.',
        selector: 'rNo',
        sortable: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'Gender',
        selector: 'gender',
        sortable: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'Result',
        selector: 'result',
        sortable: true,
    },
];

const nestedColumns = [
    {
        name: 'Subject',
        selector: 'subject',
        sortable: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'Marks',
        selector: 'marks',
        sortable: true,
    },
];


function UploadResult({ match }) {
    const data = [
        {
            sNo: 1,
            name: 'John Doe',
            rNo: '001',
            gender: 'Male',
            result: 'Pass',
            subjects: [
                { subject: 'PUNJABI (004)', marks: 'A' },
                { subject: 'FRENCH (018)', marks: 'A' },
                { subject: 'MATHEMATICS (041)', marks: 'A' },
                { subject: 'HINDI COURSE-B (085)', marks: 'A' },
                { subject: 'SCIENCE THEORY (086)', marks: 'A' },
                { subject: 'SOCIAL SCIENCE (087)', marks: 'A' },
                { subject: 'COMM.SANSKRIT (122)', marks: 'A' },
                { subject: 'ENGLISH LNG & LIT. (184)', marks: 'A' },
                { subject: 'MATHEMATICS -BASIC (241)', marks: 'A' },
                { subject: 'ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE (417)', marks: 'A' },
                { subject: 'Total Marks Obtained', marks: 495 },
                { subject: 'Total Marks', marks: 600 },
                { subject: 'Percentage', marks: '76%' },
                { subject: 'Percentage (BO5)', marks: '76%' },
            ],
        },
        // Add more data objects for other students
    ];
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
    const expandedRowRenderer = ({ subjects }) => (
        <DataTable
            columns={nestedColumns}
            data={subjects}
            noHeader
            dense
            pagination={false}
        />
    );

    const validationSchema = Yup.object({
        class: Yup.string().required("Class Name is required"),
        session: Yup.string().required("Session is required"),
        file: Yup.string().required("File is required"),
    });
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            class: "",
            session: "",
            file: "",
        },
        enableReinitialize: true,
        validationSchema,
        onSubmit: async (values) => {
            setNumber(1);
            console.log(values)
            formik.resetForm();
        },
    });
    return (
        <div className="disable-text-selection">
            <Row>
                <Colxx xxs="12">
                    <Breadcrumb heading="menu.upload-result" match={match} />
                    <Separator className="mb-5" />
                </Colxx>
            </Row>

            <Row className="mb-4">
                <Colxx xxs="12">
                    <Card>
                        <CardBody>
                            <Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                                <FormGroup row>
                                    <Label for="passwordHorizontal" sm={2}>
                                        Session
                                    </Label>
                                    <Colxx sm={10}>
                                        <Input
                                            type="text"
                                            id="emailHorizontal"
                                            placeholder='Enter session'
                                            name="session"
                                            value={formik.values.session}
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                        />
                                        {formik.touched.session && formik.errors.session && <p style={{ color: 'red', marginTop: '5px', marginBottom: '-15px' }}>{formik.errors.session}</p>}
                                    </Colxx>
                                </FormGroup>

                                <FormGroup row>
                                    <Label for="emailHorizontal" sm={2}>
                                        Class
                                    </Label>
                                    <Colxx sm={10}>
                                        <Input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="class"
                                            id="emailHorizontal"
                                            placeholder='Enter class name'
                                            value={formik.values.class}
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                        />
                                        {formik.touched.class && formik.errors.class && <p style={{ color: 'red', marginTop: '5px', marginBottom: '-15px' }}>{formik.errors.class}</p>}
                                    </Colxx>
                                </FormGroup>

                                <FormGroup row>
                                    <Label for="UploadHorizontal" sm={2}>
                                        Upload-result
                                    </Label>
                                    <Colxx sm={10}>
                                        <InputGroup>
                                            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">Upload</InputGroupAddon>
                                            <CustomInput
                                                type="file"
                                                id="UploadHorizontal"
                                                name="file"
                                                value={formik.values.file}
                                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                            />
                                        </InputGroup>
                                        {formik.touched.file && formik.errors.file && <p style={{ color: 'red', marginTop: '5px', marginBottom: '-15px' }}>{formik.errors.file}</p>}
                                    </Colxx>
                                </FormGroup>

                                <Button type='submit' color="primary">
                                    Submit
                                </Button>
                            </Form>
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                </Colxx>
            </Row>

            {number === 1 &&
                <Row className="mb-4">
                    <Colxx xxs="12">
                        <Card className="mb-4">
                            <CardBody>
                                <CardTitle>
                                    Result Table
                                </CardTitle>

                                <DataTable
                                    title="Session: 2022/23   Class: 10th"
                                    columns={columns}
                                    data={data}
                                    expandableRows
                                    expandableRowsComponent={expandedRowRenderer}
                                    expandableRowDisabled={() => false}
                                />

                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    </Colxx>
                </Row>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default UploadResult
```

Thanks in advance................